# Mount unit with - in path active in systemctl status, but available for Requires in unit

Tags: mount, systemd

I'm observing the following behavior and am wondering whether I'm missing something or hit a bug: I'm specifying a `.mount` unit in a `Requires` stanza in a `systemd` unit. If the path contains a `-` (which is escaped with `\\x2d` in the system unit and commands) the start fails:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/dir /tmp/dir-0 /tmp/dir0
$ sudo mount --bind /tmp/dir /tmp/dir-0
```

causes `sudo systemctl status tmp-dir\\x2d0.mount` to correctly print

```
● tmp-dir\x2d0.mount - /tmp/dir-0
   Loaded: loaded (/proc/self/mountinfo)
   Active: active (mounted) since Tue 2018-08-21 20:34:58 CEST; 34s ago
    Where: /tmp/dir-0
     What: /dev/mapper/root-root
```

however a `systemd` unit `test.service` containing

```
[Unit]
Requires=tmp-dir\\x2d0.mount

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/echo "Hello world!"
```

to fail to start due to

```
> sudo systemctl start test.service 
Failed to start test.service: Unit tmp-dir\\x2d0.mount not found.
```

If I use `/tmp/dir0` as mountpoint and adjust the `Requires` unit it works fine. `systemctl daemon-reload` has been called between all changes.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Requires=tmp-dir\\x2d0.mount
```

to

```
Requires=tmp-dir\x2d0.mount
```

in your `.service` file.